# The timeout specified has expired for a Wordpress cron

Tags: php, apache, cron

I am trying to run a script every three hours on my Wordpress installation using cron. The script consists of a foreach which is quite slow to execute. In local the cron job works well but in production on my Vultr server, I get the following error:

> [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 32369:tid 139804532532992] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client 45.11.111.111:47111] AH01075: Error dispatching request to : (polling)

I am a web developer but I have little to no experience in administrating a server. I read some answers about this problem and modified the timeout in /etc/apache2-rc/conf.d/mysite.conf :

```
    <Proxy ${SOCK}>
        ProxySet keepalive=On
        ProxySet timeout=999990000000000
        ProxySet retry=0
    </Proxy>
```

This still doesn't work. Any idea how I could solve this problem? Thanks.

### Update

The solution was to restart Apache. Thanks Noman.

Comment: Did you restart apache after changing the timeout value?

Comment: No, do you know how I can restart it? Will a server restart make it?

Comment: Yes it should. You are using apache as server? Use this command: 
service httpd restart

Comment: If you are not a root user, add "sudo", sudo service httpd restart. By the way, I am assuming you must have SSH access of the server and you can write these commands in a terminal (i.e. putty, etc).

Comment: I get this when doing this command: "Failed to restart httpd.service: Unit httpd.service not found." I just tried to restart the whole server from the Vultr interface.

Comment: Try this: service apache2 restart

Comment: It works!! Thanks a ton man!

Comment: I have added it as an answer. Could you please accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "ProxySet timeout" attribute should do the trick.

Please attempt to restart web server and check again.

You can restart by:

```
service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Thank you, this was the problem!